# EJS not rendering after using electron builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ejs, electron-builder

I am trying to render an `ejs` file in my `electron.js` app. I am loading the ejs file using the following skeleton:

```
const ejs = require('ejs')

ejs.renderFile('views/list.ejs', { data: listData }, { root: __dirname }, function (err, str) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        mainWindow.loadURL('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(str));
});
```

Now this is working properly in the dev environment(i.e. using `electron .` command), but when I build the app using `electron-builder`, and run the app, the `ejs` does not render and is just a blank page with undefined printed.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I too have this issue! Did you ever find a solution @akshayks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for posterity: I FIGURED IT OUT (ish)

For some reason, `ejs.renderFile()` needs an absolute path when the app is built with `electron-builder`.

So, you need to do like this:
`${path.join(__dirname,` ./${consequence}.ejs`)}`

```
ejs.renderFile(`${path.join(__dirname, `views/list.ejs`)}`, { data: listData }, { root: __dirname }, 
    function (err, str) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        mainWindow.loadURL('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(str));
    }
);
```

As to WHY this is the case, I do not know (since __dirname is included as "root" option param...I'm guessing there is a bug.

Comment: I ended up using the `ejs-electron` library for my project and it worked for me since my previous approach was just taking up too much time to debug. But thanks for solving it.